# Does Apache Nifi QueryDatabaseTableRecord automatically orders data?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` with a Maximum-value column.

Does Nifi automatically orders the data fetch by this column?

If not, the data may come unordered and it might miss some records.

Here is the setup:

[image: Nifi QueryDatabaseTableRecord]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **GenerateTableFetch** for this one - you can control the extraction logic using a column that changes when the data changes in the table and also it preserves the state of where the extraction is.